# Header error on my login api function using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

Here is my login function, in my NodeJs API. "user_router" is an express.Router() object that my main express app uses.

```
users_router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {

    var data = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password ? md5(req.body.password) : null
    }

    var sql_retrieve = "SELECT * from user WHERE email = ?, password = ?"
    var params = [data.email, data.password]

    db_mariposa.get(sql_retrieve, params, (err, rows) => {

        // from this point on, my user  exists
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({"error":err.message});
        }

        // creates token
        const token = jwt.sign(
            { user_email: data.email },
            "secret",
            {
                expiresIn: "2h",
            }
        );

        var sql_update = "UPDATE user SET token = ? WHERE email = ?, password = ?"

        db_mariposa.run(sql_update, [token, data.email , md5(data.password)])
        
        return res.status(200).json({"my_token":token, "name": data.name, "email": data.email});

    });

});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
{
    "error": "SQLITE_ERROR: near \",\": syntax error"
}
```

And before that I was getting an error on the "if (err)" line inside my first SQLite query regarding my header data:

```
Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my authentication:

```
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {

    const token = req.headers["my_token"];

    console.log(token)

    if (!token) {
        return res.status(403).send("A token is required for authentication");
    }

    try {

        console.log("try/catch")

        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'secret');

        req.user_email = decoded;

        console.log("Valid token!")

    } catch (err) {

        return res.status(401).send("Invalid Token");
    
    }

    return next();

};
```

Comment: Did you mean `email = ? AND password = ?`?

Comment: @Konrad yep, silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I misstyped.

```
var sql_update = "UPDATE user SET token = ? WHERE email = ?, password = ?"
```

Should be:

```
var sql_update = "UPDATE user SET token = ? WHERE email = ? AND password = ?"
```